# Is there any easy to use CGLIB API to generate method interceptor without using proxy?

Tags: java, instrumentation, cglib

I want an easy to use API from cglib or some wrapper class to achieve the following class transformation, so that while I use the class without any proxy involved.

```
@Entity
public class SomeProcess extends SomeProcessBase implements Serializable {

@ToBeTransformed
public void start() {
    //do some business logics
}

}
```

After class has been transformed, I expect it would be like this:

```
@Entity
public class SomeProcess extends SomeProcessBase implements Serializable {

public void start() {
    Executor.execute(new Executable() {
        public void execute() {

          //do some business logics

        }
    });

}

}
```

So while I want to call someProcess.start, i can directly use the following code:

```
SomeProcess process = new SomeProcess();
process.start();
```

Other than

```
SomeProcess process = new SomeProcess();
SomeProcess processProxy = Proxy.wrapper(process);
processProxy.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javassist http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html to change a class on the fly. Something like this:

```
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass sp = pool.get("SomeProcess");
    for (CtMethod m : sp.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (m.hasAnnotation(ToBeTransformed.class)) {
            String body = // create new body 
            m.setBody(body);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want the old body be wrapped, the old body is still useful. And I understand it's not that easy to set an enclosing class, since once there is parameter reference, they should be copied to the inner class. I don't know how to do this with javassist.

Comment: According to your answer, the new question should be: How to create a new body with the old body nested as an inner class method.

Comment: You can rename start -> start0, create new start and call start0 from it